# Who decides who can enter a jointly owned property?

Tags: united-kingdom

My partner and I are going through an acrimonious separation. I was forced out of our jointly owned house but am about to return until such time as we can sell it. He wanted to buy me out but has been so vile that I've decided not allow him. My concern is that while we are co-habiting the house, I will be subject to visits from his family who were pivotal in the breakdown of our relationship. Can I block their access?

Comment: Beware that you sound like you're trying to cut your nose off to spite your face.

Comment: I offered him the opportunity to see if he could buy me out. He then got two way too low valuations done in my absence which would’ve seen me about £20k out of pocket.

Comment: Since he''d be buying you out, it's your job to get the valuation.  As things a now, you're simply throwing rocks at his valuation.  As well you might, since he has a conflict of interest.   When it's entirely your people working for you, *then* you can believe it.

Answer (score 13):

Joint tenancy means that you both have equal (full) rights to the entire property, so just as you don't his permission to live there or to invite guests, he doesn't either. Unless they threaten you in some way (and you get a court order barring them from entering), there is no legal means to deprive an owner of their property rights, while they are still an owner.

Comment: Why does the right to invite guests trump the right(?) to keep people off your property?

Comment: @pipe: you forego that right when you entered a joint-ownership situation.

Comment: @pipe because in many states, if they allowed one owner to unilaterally eject people it would cause a grey area with trespassing laws, and by extension open up a huge can of worms when it comes to defense of the home.

Comment: This sounds pretty petty but, as I said, it’s been very acrimonious. How about him using my solely owned property to entertain them? Around 80% of everything in the house is mine - from the chairs they'd sit on to the cups they’d drink from...

Comment: He’s also threatened to put my belongings outside.

Comment: @Logarr There are no "states" involved though, this is in the UK

Comment: @DeborahCameron If they are your belongings and not shared belongings, you can move them to a safe place before that happens. You'll have to find such a place eventually, your current situation isn't going to hold by the sound of it.

Comment: If both people have "equal full rights", in the current acrimonious situation, what would be the legal position if for example the OP moved out and requested the utility companies to cut off all supplies, and paid any fees involved themselves? Could the other party compel the OP to pay part or all of the cost of reconnection and be jointly liable for any future bills?

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, it very much appreciated. Deborah

Comment: In a marriage relationship or civil union type relationship, the court handling a divorce can typically enter "temporary orders" to govern these issues. But, in the absence of a marriage or formal legal relationship, the grounds for intervention become much muddier and weaker.